# Python Regular Expression: No space in between

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following string:

"......(some chars) aaa bbb @@@8/13/2018 ......(some chars)"

The `@@@` in the string represent some random characters. `@@@`'s length is unknown and it could be None (just "aaa bbb 8/13/2018").

My goal is to find the date from the string (8/13/2018) and the starting index of `@@@`.

I currently used the following code:

```
m = re.search(r'\s.*?([0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{2,})', str)
m.groups()[0] ## The date
m.start() ## index of @@@
```

But the regex is matching `bbb @@@8/13/2018` instead of `@@@8/13/2018`

I also tried change the regex to:

```
r'\s(?!\s).*?[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{2,}'
r'\s(?!\s)*?[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{2,}'
```

But neither of them works.

I will be appreciated for any help or comments. Thank you.

Comment: `@*(?:\d+/){2}\d+`??? or even `\S+(?:\d+/){2}\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to believe you are looking for:

`@*(?:\d{1,2}/){2}\d{2,4}` or even `\S*(?:\d{1,2}/){2}\d{2,4}`

This is simply saying:

- `\S*` start with 0 or more non-space charaters.
- `(?:\d{1,2}/){2}` find two groups of  `\d{1,2}/` but do not capture them. ie not capturing:  `(?:..)`.this will match the month and date part 8/13/. `\d{1,2}` means atleast one digit and atmost two digits
- `\d{2,4}` match the year .Atleast 2 digits and atmost 4 digits

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. There is still a lot I need to learn about regex.

Answer (score 1):

Using a part of your regex, I think you mean something like this

`r'\S*([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]{2,})'`

https://regex101.com/r/dxF4sT/1

To find the starting index, it would be where the match was found.

Note that `\S` will find all consecutive *non-whitespace*.
You can change this to other things like `[@a-zA-Z]` etc..., just add it to the class.

Comment: Thank you, it works for most of the time except cases like '@@@08/13/2018'

Comment: @TooYoung - You've got a problem there my friend, maybe you should have asked before you chose an answer. Don't need my help ..

Comment: Still thank you for your help. I don't know what's wrong accepting an answer that works.